# API for a tree structure

Tags: api, rest, mongodb

I have a web service that allows my users to manage music festivals. Each festival has a location, several stages and on each stage several artists.

So I have 4 entities : festival, location, stage and artist that can be represented as a tree structure. I need a simple CRUD for these.

In REST API terms, the obvious implementation would be to have 4 URIs (/festivals, /locations, /stages and /artists, potentially followed by a /id) that will be requested with POST, PUT, GET or DELETE.

But, for my needs, locations, stages and artists have no interests if they are not linked to a festival. So why would I need to implement CRUD methods for these entities ? A CRUD only for the festival entity shouldn't be enough ?

The drawbacks :

- The clients of my API (website, native mobile apps, other services...) can't read a sub-entity of my festival. But, as I said before, sub-entities of my service have no interest without the festival they belong to. So each client will have to get the festival, the whole festival, and therefore every sub-entities.
- Those same clients will need to update the whole festival even if they just modified the name of an artist. This seems to be the worst drawback but, after all, is it that bad to send the full json of my festival (maximum a few kb) instead of a partial json that'll be a bit shorter ?

The advantage :

- I need to code, test and maintain 4 methods instead of 16 (and even more if there were more entities to manage, assuming they keep this simple tree structure).

Technically, I'll be doing this with the lovely combo node.js + mongodb (it has not much to do with the situation except that it's the super tree friendly aspect of mongodb that makes me think about it).

What do you think of this approach? Do you see other drawbacks with this idea?

Comment: I think you're trying to minimize work and maximize risk. I say go for the more correct data storage, and maybe provide a final overview that pulls everything at once, and even call it FestivalOverview...

Comment: Hello Greg, this is a bit more suitable for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions) than Stack Overflow (being a purely design question), however although you are giving us enough technical details, you aren't telling us almost anything about your functional requirements. If there's a use case calling for an artist search, your schema simply won't work. And if not, please make it abundantly clear. In any case, update your question to give us an exact set of functional requirements, and then flag for moderation attention and ask for it to be moved to Programmers.

Answer (score 3):

Your justification for having the smaller API looks sound.  However, make sure you're also considering the complications of concurrent data access.

The larger the amount of data you package into a single unit, the more chances you have for change conflicts.  For example, if you have two users modifying the same `festival`, one changing the stage name and the other changing an artist name, you could have a race condition where one update overwrites the changes made in the other.  Obviously, you can have race conditions even if you have a more granular API, but merging everything into one unit amplifies the problem.

Comment: Indeed! I had also this problem in mind, but as a festival belong to a single user, I wasn't thinking of 2 users modifying the same festival. 
I was thinking that the same user can make concurrent access by modifying at the same time the same festival from the website and from the API for instance.
But yes, it can be a problem, thank you for pointing that out.